# Hold Value to a variable inside the linux bash do loop

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

I need to define a global variable for further refrence

This is my code

```
    # .bashrc
    LOCAL_CONF_DIR='/var/www/vhosts/vhost/test.conf'

   cat ${LOCAL_CONF_DIR} | while read LINE
   do
   if [ "ServerName" == "${LINE:0:10}" ]; then
       s=( $LINE )
       SERVER_NAME=$s[1];
   fi
   done
echo $SERVER_NAME
```

Doesn't work for me RHE Linux 6.0

many thanks ;)

Comment: modify your question with updates - not the answers

Comment: Dhanan, I believe you'll love reading : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls  (and the rest of that site, the FAQ and the BashGuide being 2 other good read). It would have warned you about the danger of subshells, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if syntax` isn't correct and your loop should not be using `cat`. Use this code:

```
SERVER_NAME=""
while read -r LINE
do
   if [ "${LINE:0:10}" = "ServerName" ]; then
       SERVER_NAME="${LINE:10}"
   fi
done < "${LOCAL_CONF_DIR}"

echo "$SERVER_NAME"
```

Comment: Note that the spaces inside `[` ... `]` are significant, too.

Comment: @dhanan: Just to clarify anubhava's correct answer and its most important part : if you use `cmd | ...`, the `...` part is done in a subshell. Hence any modification in `...` is lost at the end of `...`'s execution, and the parent shell doesn't "inherit" the variables changed within `...`. Here, your `cat | while .....` made every change in variables within the while occur in a subshell, and to be lost upon exiting the while loop. (+1 to anubhava)

Comment: @OlivierDulac: Thanks so much. That's a perfect explanation.

Comment: +1, but don't use `==` in place of `=` inside `[ ... ]`; some shells allow it, but those same shells usually provide the superior `[[ ... ]]` command as well.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks, updated. It was a direct copy/paste from OP's question actually and I didn't pay much attention there.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava i got the issue its easy to do without cat cheers

Comment: Sure :)im new to stack,  all things like greek ;

Comment: @anubhava that was mistake ; thnaks for highlighting this